# Importing Webform Submissions to create content

Tags: webforms

Is it possible to use data a user submits via a webform via a simple import into a site.  It would not be the same site.  The webform is being used to collect specific data.

e.g.  webform data = user name, address, photo file, csv file submitted via webform in site A

webform submission data imported in to site B

Answer (score 0):

You can make a view of your results (built-in webform) and with the https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export module turn in it into a CSV. Plenty of ways to import that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Webform Import module for Drupal 7: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_import